# Is there a quick way to zero all the static members of a class?

Tags: c++, class, static

I have a class with static members that get reset to zero each loop, so something like:

```
class Stats
{
   static inline int counter1, counter2;
   static inline float time;
   static void resetStats() 
   {
       counter1 = 0;
       counter2 = 0;
       time = 0.f;
   }
}
```

With a non-static class I can create a new object of it with zero-initialization and copy to the object I want to reset the values of. If it's possible I just have to remember that for each member I create in it I also add it to the "resetStats()" function.

Comment: If theses variables need to be reset to zero every loop iteration, why not just declare the  variables you need in the loop and set them to zero?

Comment: @JohnFilleau Yes only static members. I've been told that if it isn't instantiated then then a static class or namespace is conceptually better. In a case like this though if it's that much easier to zero all the members I may make it a non-static class

Comment: @Zebrafish if the members are not static, you can do something like `*this = Stats{}` in the reset function. But also consider creating the whole variable simply inside the for loop instead of resetting it every loop iteration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the the variables non-static members of a class, and use a static instance of that class. This way you can use value initialisation to set all members to zero:

```
class Stats
{
    static inline struct {
        int counter1, counter2;
        float time;
    } data;

    static void resetStats() 
    {
        data = {};
    }
```

---

That said, static variables are global state. Gobal state should be avoided.

> that get reset to zero each loop

This sounds like ideal use case for non-static storage.

Comment: I get what you mean by global state should be avoided, but if I need to write to these variables across my entire program from different functions (for measuring times etc.) how should I go about this?

Comment: @Zebrafish Depends. There aren't enough details to design a solution.